# Who calls the probe() of driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How does `probe()` call gets called? Who calls it? As per my understanding, `__init()` registers `driver` and then somehow `probe()` is called to `register` the device data and `irq` etc. How exactly it happens?

I am working on touchscreen driver and its `__init` registers itself to `i2c driver`. Then probe expect `i2c_clien`t data which returns null. I want to track where it gets filled.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Long story short: the probe() function of the driver is called as a result of calling the `register_driver` for that specific bus. More precisely, it's called by the `probe()` of that `bus_type` structure. In your case: `i2c_bus_type`.

Here's the call chain in your I2C case:

- i2c_register_driver
- driver_register
- bus_add_driver
- driver_attach
- __driver_attach (for your device)
- driver_probe_device
- really_probe
- i2c_device_probe (this is what dev->bus->probe is for an i2c driver)
- your_probe_function

Comment: When does `i2c_register_driver` get called? Is it when you call `i2cdetect` and it finds a device on the bus with a name that matches a registered `struct i2c_driver`?

Answer (score 16):

I have prepared a graph that traces platform drive's probe function. You are working with I2C driver which AFAIK is a platform driver. I hope this helps you to trace the issue.

[image]

Also, look into following link to see the discussion on kernelnewbies.

https://www.mail-archive.com/kernelnewbies%40kernelnewbies.org/msg12423.html

Answer (score 8):

Lets consider an example of a `platform device driver`:

1. The starting trigger function for the `driver->probe()` callback is the `module_init()` macro called while loading the driver; this `macro` is defined in `include/linux/module.h`.
2. `module_init(my_driver_init)` has the callback to `my_driver_init()` function. `my_driver_init()` function should have a call to `platform_driver_register(my_driver)`
3. `platform_driver_register(my_driver)` assigns `my_driver -> probe()` handle to generic `drv -> probe()` and calls the `driver_register(my_driver)` function.
4. `driver_register(my_driver)` function adds `my_driver` to the platform bus and calls `driver_attach()` function.
5. In the same way, even the `platform_device` needs to attach to the platform bus.
6. Finally, only if the `driver_match_device()` returns success based on the `.name` & `.id_table` of the `driver` matches in the platform devices list that comes either from `ACPI/DTS`, then the `driver_probe_device()` gets called that has the `drv->probe()` callback.

Answer (score 4):

**@iSegFault** : probe() will be called to make sure that the device exist and the functionality is fine.If device is not hot-pluggable, functionality of probe() can be put inside init() method.This will reduce driver's run time memory footprint. P.S [link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt)

Probe() happens at the time of device boot or when device is connected.For a "platform" device the probe function is invoked when a platform device is registered and it's device name matches the name specified on the device driver. P.S [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.kernelnewbies/37050)

The i2c_detect function probes the I2C adapter, looking for the different addresses specified in the addr_data structure. If a device is found, the chip_detect function then is called. P.S [link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/writing-clients).

One link that will surely clear your doubt. P.S [link](http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/2669326/)

In kernel 2.4.29, i can show you that how does probe happen ? Please see below (File name: **drivers/acorn/char/pcf8583.c**)

```
static struct i2c_driver pcf8583_driver = {
name:       "PCF8583",
id:     I2C_DRIVERID_PCF8583,
flags:      I2C_DF_NOTIFY,
attach_adapter: pcf8583_probe, /* This will be called from i2c-core.c P.S see below function i2c_add_driver()*/
detach_client:  pcf8583_detach,
command:    pcf8583_command
};
```

File Name: **drivers/i2c/i2c-core.c**

```
int i2c_add_driver(struct i2c_driver *driver)
{
    ........................
    ........................

    /* now look for instances of driver on our adapters
     */
    if (driver->flags& (I2C_DF_NOTIFY|I2C_DF_DUMMY)) {
        for (i=0;i<I2C_ADAP_MAX;i++)
            if (adapters[i]!=NULL)
                /* Ignore errors */
                driver->attach_adapter(adapters[i]); /*This is a location from where probe is called. Pointer **driver** is of type **pcf8583_driver** which you have passed into this function*/
    }
    ADAP_UNLOCK();
    return 0;
}
```

Few important links:

1. http://www.slideshare.net/varunmahajan06/i2c-subsystem-in-linux2624
2. http://www.programering.com/a/MjNwcTMwATM.html
3. http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6717
4. http://www.developermemo.com/2943157/
5. http://free-electrons.com/doc/kernel-architecture.pdf
6. http://www.techques.com/question/1-3014627/Probe-problem-when-writing-a-I2C-device-driver

In PCI for kernel-2.4.29, it gets called when vendor and device id are identified. PCI bus driver do this for you. Please see below code:

File Name: **drivers/pci/pci.c**

```
static int pci_announce_device(struct pci_driver *drv, struct pci_dev *dev)
{
   const struct pci_device_id *id;
   int ret = 0;
   if (drv->id_table) {
    id = pci_match_device(drv->id_table, dev); /* check for device presence*/
    if (!id) {
     ret = 0;
     goto out;
    }
   } else
  id = NULL;
  dev_probe_lock();
  if (drv->probe(dev, id) >= 0) { /* This is a location from where probe is called*/
   dev->driver = drv;
   ret = 1;
   }
   dev_probe_unlock();
  out:
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probe function will be called for every interface of the detected device except the ones which are already registered.

Answer (score 0):

Probe function will gets called when **name** will match form drivers structure to device structure. Below mentioned eg for both driver and device structure.

1: Driver Structure

```
 static struct driver your_driver = {
        .driver = {
              .name = YUR_NAME,

                  },
```

eg.

```
static struct i2c_driver l3gd20_driver = {
        .driver = {

                        .name = l3gd20_gyr,

                   }
```

2: Device Structure

```
static structure device  your_devices = {
              .name = YUR_NAME,
              },
```

eg.

```
static struct i2c_board_info mxc_i2c2_board_info[] __initdata = {
                {
                I2C_BOARD_INFO("l3gd20_gyr", 0x6a),
                 },
```

Note: When name(l3gd20_gyr) from driver and device will match your probe will gets call.

Answer (score 0):

#probe()

The probe function is used to initialize and manage a platform device when it is detected by the kernel.

Here's how it works:

**1. Device Detection:** When the Linux kernel initializes or when a platform device is physically connected or detected, the kernel scans the system's device tree (for ARM-based systems) or ACPI tables (for x86 systems) to identify platform devices.

**2.Matching with Compatible Strings:** Each platform device is associated with a compatible string that describes the device's type and features. The kernel compares the compatible strings of detected devices with the compatible strings specified in platform drivers.

**3.Probe Function Call:** When a platform device with a compatible string matching a platform driver is detected, the kernel calls the probe function of that driver.

**4.Driver Initialization:** Inside the probe function, the driver performs initialization tasks for the specific device. This includes setting up the device's hardware, registering it with relevant kernel subsystems, allocating resources (like memory regions or IRQs), and preparing it for operation.

**5.Registration with Subsystems:** The probe function often registers the platform device with kernel subsystems, making it accessible to other parts of the kernel and user-space applications.

**6.Driver Usage:** Once the probe function has successfully initialized the device and completed any necessary setup, the device is ready for use, and the driver can respond to requests and events related to that device.

**Note:**
probe() should in general verify that the specified device hardware actually exists.