# Who calls "probe" function in driver code?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, spi

I am trying to understand [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c#L1288) driver code of mcspi for omap2 panda board.

I don't understand who calls the `probe` function and what is the call chain in [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c#L1288) driver code?

How does the driver is informed when the device is connected?

Comment: Please, add line numbers in "spi-omap2-mcspi.c"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who calls the probe() of driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578582/who-calls-the-probe-of-driver)

Comment: 213 /* module_platform_driver() - Helper macro for drivers that don't do
214  * anything special in module init/exit.  This eliminates a lot of
215  * boilerplate.  Each module may only use this macro once, and
216  * calling it replaces module_init() and module_exit()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The probe function from `spi-omap2-mcspi.c` is saved in the `static struct platform_driver omap2_mcspi_driver`, which is registered with `module_platform_driver(omap2_mcspi_driver);` (at the end of file). The  `module_platform_driver` macro, defined in [platform_device.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.13/source/include/linux/platform_device.h#L218) will pass the struct to  `platform_driver_register` macro and  `__platform_driver_register` function from [drivers/base/platform.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.13/source/drivers/base/platform.c#L532)

```
527 /**
528  * __platform_driver_register - register a driver for platform-level devices
529  * @drv: platform driver structure
530  * @owner: owning module/driver
531  */
532 int __platform_driver_register(struct platform_driver *drv,
533                                 struct module *owner)
534 {
...
536         drv->driver.bus = &platform_bus_type;
537         if (drv->probe)
538                 drv->driver.probe = platform_drv_probe;
...
544         return driver_register(&drv->driver);
545 }
546 EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(__platform_driver_register);
```

The probe now passed to `driver_register` function from [drivers/base/driver.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.13/source/drivers/base/driver.c#L139)

```
139 /**
140  * driver_register - register driver with bus
141  * @drv: driver to register
142  *
143  * We pass off most of the work to the bus_add_driver() call,
144  * since most of the things we have to do deal with the bus
145  * structures.
146  */
147 int driver_register(struct device_driver *drv)
148 {
...
154         if ((drv->bus->probe && drv->probe) ||
...
167         ret = bus_add_driver(drv);
...
178 }
```

So, now the driver is registered in the bus (`platform_bus_type`).

Actual call to probe is done via `driver_probe_device` [drivers/base/dd.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.13/source/drivers/base/dd.c#L360), then `really_probe` (same file line 265):

```
265 static int really_probe(struct device *dev, struct device_driver *drv)
266 {
...
270         pr_debug("bus: '%s': %s: probing driver %s with device %s\n",
271                  drv->bus->name, __func__, drv->name, dev_name(dev));
...
287         if (dev->bus->probe) {
288                 ret = dev->bus->probe(dev);       /// <<<< HERE
289                 if (ret)
290                         goto probe_failed;
291         } else if (drv->probe) {
292                 ret = drv->probe(dev);            /// <<<< OR HERE
293                 if (ret)
294                         goto probe_failed;
295         }
296 
297         driver_bound(dev);
298         ret = 1;
299         pr_debug("bus: '%s': %s: bound device %s to driver %s\n",
300                  drv->bus->name, __func__, dev_name(dev), drv->name);
301         goto done;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Can you please explain the call chain?
And how does the driver is informed when the device is connected?

Comment: Really I can't. I only can search code or some sites in internet, may be like this: http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/1120807/ "registration phase: Platform_driver_register() > driver_register() > bus_add_driver() > driver_attach() > bus_for_each_dev (), in each hanging on .. Platform BUS the equipment for __driver_attach(), > driver_probe_device() to determine the drv-> bus-> match() executed successfully, through a pointer to perform platform_match > strncmp (pdev > name, the drv > name, BUS_ID_SIZE) call really_probe (actual corresponding equipment platform_driver > probe (platform_device)"

Comment: That's an useful link. Thank you !

Comment: (it was useful, but bit outdated).. Check also this link ->> https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt "Device Naming and Driver Binding...Driver binding is performed automatically by the driver core, invoking
driver probe() after finding a match between device and driver.  If the probe() succeeds, the driver and device are bound as usual.  There are three different ways to find such a match: ...//read this//",  also check early_platform_driver_probe()

Comment: The http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt was the link. I skipped interesting part, so just go to http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt  and read the "Device Naming and Driver Binding" section

Comment: This all assumes that the `device_driver` knows its bus/buses. However when being defined in the `platform_driver` in the driver code, the only fields of the `device_driver` being filled out on the spot are the `name` and `of_match_table`, like in the [pcm5102.c](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-5.15.y/sound/soc/codecs/pcm5102a.c), what about all the other info, where/when is it filled out? None of the calls mentioned by you seem to do that.